# How to change from false to true

Tags: r

When I run is.data.table(data.table) == TRUE the answer displayed back is false how do I make this true. I have tried to run the code but it doesn't work

Comment: Can you make a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `is.data.table` returns a logical vector.  It doesn't need to further do a comparison

```
library(data.table)
is.data.table(as.data.table(mtcars))
#[1] TRUE
```

If it is not a data.table, convert to data.table with `setDT`

```
setDT(dt1)
```

Comment: I thought having changing this fact would solve my problem but it hasn't I am still getting this message Error in `:=`(aao, (Y > 649)) : 
  Check that is.data.table(DT) == TRUE. Otherwise, := and `:=`(...) are defined for use in j, once only and in particular ways. See help(":=").

Comment: @Insea can you convert to data.table first i.e. `setDT(yourdata)` and then apply the code

Comment: Not sure where that is